# Is there a way to call a class in a global namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

I have a tough time wording this question but here's my code to start:

```
namespace UserInterface
{
   class UiClass
   {
   };
}

namespace Project
{
   namespace UserInterface
   {

   }
}


namespace Project
{
   UserInterface::UiClass uiClass;
}
```

So that code won't work because a `UserInterface` is a global namespace but it's also inside `Project` so when I instaniate `UiClass` inside `Project` it tries to look inside `Project->UserInterface` instead of just `UserInterface`.  Is there a some way to be specific that I want to use the global `UserInterface` and not the one inside `Project` or do I need to change my design?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can force the name lookup to begin at the global scope using a leading `::`.

```
::UserInterface::UiClass uiClass;
```